# Show() not working in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

//Code added by Nitesh for RFE 670082 starts here
    jQuery("input[name='hideLineItemColumns_quote']").click(function () {
        alert(jQuery(this).attr('checked'));
    if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')){
            var columnName = $.trim($(this).val()).replace('\u00a0','');

        $('thead.line-item-grid-header tr th').filter(function () 
            {
                if($.trim($('div', this).text()).replace(' ','') == columnName){
                    indexValue = $(this).index();
                    //Hiding body columns
                    jQuery('.line-item-grid-body').children('tr').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('td:eq('+indexValue+')').hide();
                    });
                    //Hiding footer columns
                    jQuery('.line-item-grid-footer').children('tr').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('th:eq('+indexValue+')').hide();
                    });
                    return true;
            };
        }).hide();
     }
     else{
            var columnName = $.trim($(this).text()).replace('\u00a0','');

        $('thead.line-item-grid-header tr th').filter(function () 
            {
                if($.trim($('div', this).text()).replace(' ','') == columnName){
                    indexValue = $(this).index();
                    //Showing body columns
                    jQuery('.line-item-grid-body').children('tr').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('td:eq('+indexValue+')').show();
                    });
                    //Showing footer columns
                    jQuery('.line-item-grid-footer').children('tr').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).children('th:eq('+indexValue+')').show();
                    });
                    return true;
            };
        }).show();
     }
});
```

Comment: You need to strip out about 98% of this and only post the applicable code. Nobody is going to read through all of this.

Comment: Yeah, posting this much code for such a basic problem indicates that you haven't even tried to narrow down where in your code the problem is.

Comment: sorry about that..I accidentally copied all my code

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if(jQuery(this).attr('checked')){
```

to

```
if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
```

Comment: tried...no luck !!...once the code hides the column, it never shows it back..I can see that it is running statements included in else statement but looks like .show() is doing nothing

Comment: Did you try debugging using firebug?

Comment: Then the best bet is to post the HTML and JS at jsfiddle.net